# Хлеб черствый или свежий?

Tags: этимология

"Забавно, но в чешском и словацком языках слово čerstvý означает "**свежий**"!

У Шанского "черствый" -  это твердый  предмет, которым можно рубить/резать, бить, ударять (корень **ker**, сравнить: корнать, короткий).

Черных корень **"ker"** связывает с глаголами **крутить**, вертеть: вёрткий, проворный, увертливый, поэтому свежий, потом крепкий, твердый, то есть черствый.

Кто же из них прав?

Вообще говоря, область применения этого слова довольно однообразная: **черствый хлеб (часто как символ бедности) да черствый человек**, исключения редкие, например:

Я вошел. Те же комнаты были; Здесь ворчал недовольный старик; Мы беседы его не любили, Нас страшил его черствый язык (Н. Огарев).

Comment: Да чешский язык для русского вообще необычный. Вот этим летом был в Праге, сам в этом убедился. Pozor — внимание, sleva — скидка и пр. Это я просто упомянул. :)

Comment: Еще можно вспомнить "uroda" - "красавица", в чешском и польском это слово имеет прямо противоположное значение. Корни общие, а у разных славянских народов получают разное толкование.

Comment: В книге "Почему так, а не иначе?" Лев Успенский, М.: 1967. очень подробно объясняется связь таких слов.

Comment: А пара свежий/черствый там тоже разбирается?

Comment: со свежим, однако, русский не одинок: польский świeży; сербский, хорватский - свеж, svježe; болгарский свеж. Видимо, все же аномалия в чешском и словацком, хотя, все равно, интересно, почему.

Answer (score 1):

Не нашла исследований конкретно этого слова, но осмелюсь предположить, что это различие значений объясняется значением слова в праязыке, от которого произошли современные слова в чешском и русском. Судя по тому, что написано в словаре Фасмера:

> Ближайшая этимология: чёрств, черства́, чёрство, диал. чвёрстый, укр. черстви́й "черствый, сильный, свежий", др.-русск. чьрствъ "твердый; сухой, черствый; безупречный; ясный; значительный", болг. чевръ́ст, чвръст "жесткий, крепкий, ловкий, бодрый", сербохорв. чвр̑ст, чвр́ста "крепкий, жесткий, полный, мясистый", словен. čŕstǝv, čvrst "крепкий, ядреный, бодрый, свежий", чеш., слвц. čerstvý "свежий, бодрый", польск. czerstwy "свежий, бодрый, крепкий, черствый" (из *czarstwy, вероятно, под влиянием czerstwieć; см. Лось, Gr. polska I, 67), в.-луж. čerstwy "бодрый".
>   Дальнейшая этимология: Праслав. *čьrstvъ неоднократно сравнивали с др.-инд. kr̥tsnás "полный, окончательный" и лат. crassus "толстый, грубый" (Бругман, Totalität 55 и сл.; Фик I, 25; Бернекер I, 171; Вальде -- Гофм. I, 285 и сл.; Майрхофер 259). Это сближение весьма недостоверно ввиду того факта, что лат. crassus расценивается как экспрессивное образование (Мейе -- Эрну 263 и сл.), связь которого с лат. crātis "плетение", гот. haúrds "дверь" и т. д. весьма сомнительна, вопреки Бернекеру (там же). Более удачно сравнение с гот. hardus "жесткий, твердый", греч. κρατύς "сильный", κρατερός "более сильный", κράτος "сила" (И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 33; Цупица, GG. 109; Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 40; Брюкнер 76; Миккола, Ursl. Gr. 3, 27). Другие сравнивают čьrstvъ с др.-исл. herstr "резкий", лит. ker̃štas "гнев" (И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 501; Бецценбергер, KZ 22, 479). Неясно.

слово в праязыке означало "крепкий", у которого может быть несколько синонимов. Русский язык унаследовал это слово по синонимическому ряду крепкий-твердый-сухой-черствый, а чешский, видимо, по другому значению: крепкий - свежий (не вялый)

Comment: *по другому значению: крепкий - свежий (не вялый)* - нет, это вряд ли, судя даже по вашей цитате (из Фасмера, видимо), здесь не такая семантика. Вялость здесь ни при чем, это Успенский немного нагородил в этом направлении - от него и пошло.  А тут прямая аналогия, достаточно сравнить и противопоставьте западно и южнославянский ряды значений. Черствый получается - сухой, лишенный влаги, т.е. пропеченный.